# How to Draw diagrams (Charts) in word automation using vectors + Ms Graph with C# office interop word library

Tags: c#, office-interop, desktop-application, word-automation

so heres the code released by Microsoft and i wonder
how to **insert a chart** when getting *vectors* from an **svg** file into word in this process?

```
//Insert a chart.
Word.InlineShape oShape;
object oClassType = "MSGraph.Chart.8";
wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oShape = wrdRng.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ref oClassType, ref oMissing, 
ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

//Demonstrate use of late bound oChart and oChartApp objects to
//manipulate the chart object with MSGraph.
object oChart;
object oChartApp;
oChart = oShape.OLEFormat.Object;
oChartApp = oChart.GetType().InvokeMember("Application",
BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oChart, null);

//Change the chart type to Line.
object[] Parameters = new Object[1];
Parameters[0] = 4; //xlLine = 4
oChart.GetType().InvokeMember("ChartType", BindingFlags.SetProperty,
null, oChart, Parameters);

//Update the chart image and quit MSGraph.
oChartApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Update",
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oChartApp, null);
oChartApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Quit",
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oChartApp, null);
//... If desired, you can proceed from here using the Microsoft Graph 
//Object model on the oChart and oChartApp objects to make additional
//changes to the chart.

//Set the width of the chart.
oShape.Width = oWord.InchesToPoints(6.25f);
oShape.Height = oWord.InchesToPoints(3.57f);
```

so how to insert diagrams (with vectors) using office interop word ?  some **help** dear developers, *thank you* ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6842716/johng  would u or anyone who knows more than me check this out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Theres no need to use MsGraph as long as theres an existing .svg file , u can approach it like a picture and add it to the document,
like this :

```
//define a range with the assigned value of end of doc
 Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
//add image path
string img = "C:\\Users\\a_shi\\Desktop\\svgsample.svg";


// add a picture by passing the image path, using AddPicture method of InlineShapes interface
    wrdRng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgpath);
```

done!